# JCR/Jackrabbit - How to make a non-trivial change to a property definition?

Tags: jcr

I have a custom node definition that looks like that:

```
[kl:customer]
    - kl:title (string) < 'MR', 'MRS', 'MS'
    ...
```

Now, I want to add `'FAMILY'` to be an allowed value for the title-property. How can I update my definition without getting a `RepositoryException`?

Because trying to perform an update with

```
[kl:customer]
    - kl:title (string) < 'MR', 'MRS', 'MS', 'FAMILY'
    ...
```

leads to an error:

> Error importing node type: javax.jcr.RepositoryException: The
>   following node type change contains non-trivial changes.Up until now
>   only trivial changes are supported...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to upgrade. I use 2.6.4 and don't get that exception.